# Issue with receiving emails

Tags: email, magento2.4, error-message, magento2.4.5

Magento Open Source 2.4.5

I am having issues with emails. They are coming through without the email body content and just "We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content."

The following is from our system.log:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded in public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Url.php(874): Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->serialize()
#1 public_html/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php(761): Magento\Framework\Url->getUrl()
#2 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate->getUrl()
#3 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Interceptor->___callParent()
#4 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#5 public_html/generated/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#6 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filter/VariableResolver/StrictResolver.php(115): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Interceptor->getUrl()
#7 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filter/VariableResolver/StrictResolver.php(90): Magento\Framework\Filter\VariableResolver\StrictResolver->handleGetterMethod()
#8 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filter/VariableResolver/StrictResolver.php(54): Magento\Framework\Filter\VariableResolver\StrictResolver->handleDataAccess()
#9 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filter/Template.php(368): Magento\Framework\Filter\VariableResolver\StrictResolver->resolve()
#10 public_html/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Filter.php(674): Magento\Framework\Filter\Template->getVariable()
#11 [internal function]: Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter->varDirective()
#12 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/LegacyDirective.php(42): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs()
#13 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filter/Template.php(192): Magento\Framework\Filter\DirectiveProcessor\LegacyDirective->process()
#14 public_html/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Filter.php(1116): Magento\Framework\Filter\Template->filter()
#15 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter->filter()
#16 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->___callParent()
#17 public_html/app/code/Magezon/PageBuilder/Plugin/Filter/Template.php(45): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#18 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magezon\PageBuilder\Plugin\Filter\Template->aroundFilter()
#19 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#20 public_html/generated/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template/Filter/Interceptor.php(50): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#21 public_html/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php(363): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->filter()
#22 public_html/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template.php(380): Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate->getProcessedTemplate()
#23 public_html/vendor/mageplaza/module-pdf-invoice/Model/Template/TransportBuilder.php(298): Magento\Email\Model\Template->processTemplate()
#24 public_html/generated/code/Mageplaza/PdfInvoice/Model/Template/TransportBuilder/Interceptor.php(68): Mageplaza\PdfInvoice\Model\Template\TransportBuilder->prepareMessage()
#25 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php(336): Mageplaza\PdfInvoice\Model\Template\TransportBuilder\Interceptor->prepareMessage()
#26 public_html/generated/code/Mageplaza/PdfInvoice/Model/Template/TransportBuilder/Interceptor.php(131): Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder->getTransport()
#27 public_html/app/code/WeltPixel/EnhancedEmail/Controller/Adminhtml/Template/Send.php(164): Mageplaza\PdfInvoice\Model\Template\TransportBuilder\Interceptor->getTransport()
#28 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): WeltPixel\EnhancedEmail\Controller\Adminhtml\Template\Send->execute()
#29 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): WeltPixel\EnhancedEmail\Controller\Adminhtml\Template\Send\Interceptor->___callParent()
#30 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): WeltPixel\EnhancedEmail\Controller\Adminhtml\Template\Send\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#31 public_html/generated/code/WeltPixel/EnhancedEmail/Controller/Adminhtml/Template/Send/Interceptor.php(23): WeltPixel\EnhancedEmail\Controller\Adminhtml\Template\Send\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#32 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): WeltPixel\EnhancedEmail\Controller\Adminhtml\Template\Send\Interceptor->execute()
#33 public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch()
#34 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch()
#35 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): WeltPixel\EnhancedEmail\Controller\Adminhtml\Template\Send\Interceptor->___callParent()
#36 public_html/app/code/WeltPixel/Backend/Plugin/Utility.php(76): WeltPixel\EnhancedEmail\Controller\Adminhtml\Template\Send\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#37 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): WeltPixel\Backend\Plugin\Utility->aroundDispatch()
#38 public_html/app/code/WeltPixel/Backend/Plugin/Utility.php(76): WeltPixel\EnhancedEmail\Controller\Adminhtml\Template\Send\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#39 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): WeltPixel\Backend\Plugin\Utility->aroundDispatch()
#40 public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(145): WeltPixel\EnhancedEmail\Controller\Adminhtml\Template\Send\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#41 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch()
#42 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): WeltPixel\EnhancedEmail\Controller\Adminhtml\Template\Send\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#43 public_html/generated/code/WeltPixel/EnhancedEmail/Controller/Adminhtml/Template/Send/Interceptor.php(32): WeltPixel\EnhancedEmail\Controller\Adminhtml\Template\Send\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#44 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): WeltPixel\EnhancedEmail\Controller\Adminhtml\Template\Send\Interceptor->dispatch()
#45 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse()
#46 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest()
#47 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch()
#48 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
#49 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#50 public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#51 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
#52 public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#53 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#54 public_html/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#55 {main} [] []
```

Is anyone able to advise how to locate the cause please?
Thanks in advance!